# AutoMapper Complex ViewModel properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I was hoping you'd be able to help me with an Automapper question I have in a test ASP.NET MVC application I’m developing.

I've had a look around and I couldn't find anything quite like what I'm trying to achieve with nested ViewModels.

Basically, I have these 2 Domain Models…

```
namespace Test.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Contact
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public Name Name { get; set; }

        public string Contact_Landline { get; set; }

        public string Contact_Mobile { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Contact_Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And..

```
namespace Test.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Name : DisplayableModel
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name_Forename { get; set; }

        public string Name_Surname { get; set; }

        public string GetFullName()
        {
            return Name_Forename + ' ' + Name_Surname;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have these 2 ViewModels…

```
namespace Test.WebUI.Models
{
    public class ContactViewModel :
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public NameViewModel Name { get; set; }

        public string Contact_Landline { get; set; }

        public string Contact_Mobile { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Contact_Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And…

```
namespace Test.WebUI.Models
{
    public class NameViewModel 
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name_Forename { get; set; }

        public string Name_Surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to return ContactViewModel to my View with the Name property populated with the Name property that populates the Contact domain object.

I have this code in my controller…

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Name, NameViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, ContactViewModel>();
var contact = Mapper.Map<Contact, ContactViewModel>(repository.Contact.Where(c => c.ID == id).Single()); 
return View(contact);
```

This is where I run into problems, my Name property is never populated.

The reason for me choosing to design my application this way is because my Views are made up of custom Model Templates so that I can consistently render NameViewModel objects without repeating code, as in this simple example…

```
@model Test.WebUI.Models.NameViewModel

First
@Model.Name_Forename
Last
@Model.Name_Surname
```

If anyone can help explain to me how I should populate the NameViewModel object of the ContactViewModel with AutoMapper I’d be really grateful.

Thanks.
Jim

Answer (score 1):

This should work out of the box as shown here:

```
public class Name 
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name_Forename { get; set; }

    public string Name_Surname { get; set; }

    public string GetFullName()
    {
        return Name_Forename + ' ' + Name_Surname;
    }
}


public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Name Name { get; set; }

    public string Contact_Landline { get; set; }

    public string Contact_Mobile { get; set; }

    public string Contact_Email { get; set; }
}

public class NameViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name_Forename { get; set; }

    public string Name_Surname { get; set; }

}

public class ContactViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public NameViewModel Name { get; set; }

    public string Contact_Landline { get; set; }

    public string Contact_Mobile { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Contact_Email { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Name, NameViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, ContactViewModel>();

        var contact = new Contact
        {
            Name = new Name
            {
                Name_Forename = "forename"
            }
        };
        var vm = Mapper.Map<Contact, ContactViewModel>(contact);
        Console.WriteLine(vm.Name.Name_Forename);
    }
}
```

prints as expected:

```
forename
```

So make sure that the `repository.Contact.Where(c => c.ID == id).Single()` call returns a `Contact` instance whose `Name` property is correctly instantiated and contains values for its properties.

Now, this being said, there are a couple of issues with your code:

- You have decorated your domain model properties with the `[HiddenInput]` attribute which is view specific stuff and belongs on your view model.
- You have decorated your view model properties with the `[Key]` attribute. That's data access specific stuff which a view model should be agnostic of.
- You are calling the `Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDest>` method inside your controller action. This is wrong. The mapping definition should be done only once for the entire lifetime of the application domain. This usually happens in a helper method called inside `Application_Start` to ensure that your mapping definitions are done only once. Inside your controller action you should only use the `Mapper.Map<TSource, TDest>` method to perform the actual mapping.

Comment: Thanks for this Darin, would you be able to advise on how I correctly instantiate the Name property? And also why this mapping is automatically done. Jim

Answer (score 0):

As said before, you should define your mappings only once (in the APP_Start folder)
Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but you could do your mapping the following way:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, ContactViewModel>()
.ForMember(c => c.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(o => o.Name_Forename + " " + o.Name.Lastname);
```

Comment: I think that looks about right but I need to return an NameViewModel object nested in the ContactViewModel object so I tried...             
`code`
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, ContactViewModel>().ForMember(c => c.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(o => o));
Mapper.CreateMap<Name, NameViewModel>();
var contact = repository.Contact.Where(c => c.ID == id).Single(); 
var vm = Mapper.Map<Contact, ContactViewModel>(contact);
return View(vm);
`code`
This gives me this error... Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oops I thought your "Name" property would be a string. For members with the exact same name, there doesnt need to be a mapping with the ForMember() function. 
Normally, you should simply define Mapper.CreateMap<Name, NameViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, ContactViewModel>(); and it should work. If it doesn't, make sure you have loaded the Properties (if lazy loading is deactivated).

Comment: Ah, now I think you may have found the real problem I'm having then. How do I load the Properties, or make sure i've loaded the properties (if lazy loading is deactivated, which i think it is).

Comment: I think you should google for a tutorial on Debugging in Visual Studio.

Comment: Would you be able to give some brief guidance on loading nested Properties for this particular instance? Thanks.

Comment: go to your Entity Data Model (EDMX file), right click, properties, set lazy loading to true, error should not appear.